# Show certain data with Flutter and Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am currently using this code to map through a whole list of todo tasks:

```
return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('todo_list').snapshots,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
    return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        document['status'] == true ?
        new ListTile(
          title: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Text(document['task'], 
                style: new TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ) : new Text("");
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

I want to show tasks that has their status to be true. However, there is an error when doing this:

```
I/flutter (21800): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21800): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (21800): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 291 pos 12: 'child != null': is
I/flutter (21800): not true.
I/flutter (21800):
I/flutter (21800): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (21800): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (21800): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (21800):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new
I/flutter (21800):
I/flutter (21800): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (21800): #2      SliverChildListDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart)
I/flutter (21800): #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:716:67)
I/flutter (21800): #4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent
```

...

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you post the actual error ?

Comment: Done. If you need the whole code, hmu. the error is much longer than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the actual result of your ternary.

```
return  document['status'] == true ?
    ....
```

That should fix things

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('todo_list').where('status', isEqualTo: false).snapshots,
```

You can query using firestore code.